# how to make sure user inputs a given set of numbers in python

Tags: python, range

I am trying to make a program in python in which a user can only input 1, 2 or 3. I tried this method but it does not work.`

```
x = input("Enter your Choice: ")    
while (x!=1 or x!=2 or x!=3):
    x = input("Enter your Choice: ")
```

Using this method it continually asks for input even if 1, 2 or 3 or any other number is keyed in. Can anybody tell please tell me why this does not work and also suggest a correct way to enter these three numbers.

Comment: Just *think* about your logic - if `x == 3` then what does `x!=1 or x!=2 or x!=3` evaluate to?

Comment: jonrsharpe is right. Think about your logics operator.

Comment: So can you please correct this or suggest an alternate way.

Comment: `while x not in (1, 2, 3):`? You really should be able to figure out how to fix the logical error, though.

Comment: Have you already tried to change the 'or' to another logics operator?

Comment: changing to and does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
def userchoicevalidator(): 
    x = input("Please Enter Your Choice: ") 
    while x not in list('123'): 
        x = input("Please Enter Your Choice: ")
```

the reason that `raw_input` wasn't working for you is because it has been deprecated in python 3. `input` is in python 3. Also note that this returns a string, not an integer, which is why your booleans checks were failing unexpectedly

Comment: Note that this will accept `'12'`, etc, but that's easy enough to fix.

Comment: Thanks very much. Worked like a charm.

Comment: @PM 2Ring  how would you fix that.

Comment: def userchoicevalidator():
    x = raw_input("Please Enter Your Choice: ")
    while (x!='1' and x!='2' and x!='3'):
      x = raw_input("Please Enter Your Choice: ")

Comment: Changing 1 to '1' in while loop fixed problems.

Comment: Edited this so that '12' will not be accepted. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1):

This is what we call a *logic error*.

The line should be like this:

```
while (x!=1 and x!=2 and x!=3):
```

That is, change the *or* to *and*.

To handle any input and give out the error if it's not 1,2 or 3, do this:

```
x = raw_input("Enter your Choice: ")    
while (x!='1' and x!='2' and x!='3'):
    x = raw_input("Enter your Choice: ")
```

Comment: def userchoicevalidator():
    x = raw_input("Please Enter Your Choice: ")
    while (x!=1 and x!=2 and x!=3):
      x = raw_input("Please Enter Your Choice: ")

Comment: this is what i wrote it asks for input indefinitely without stopping.

Comment: @abdullahaquarius well does `'1' == 1`?

Comment: well changing raw_input to input worked but now it gives an error if a letter is typed.

Comment: how can i make the program so it asks again if anything other than 1, 2, 3 is typed even a string.

Comment: `input()` does `eval(raw_input())` hence you use only `raw_input()`. The solution provided by @itsols works. You missed the quotes in your code.